# .NET printing coordinate conversion

Tags: .net, vb.net, printing, coordinate-transformation

I can't get a simple answer to this.
I have pixel coordinates, I want to print an image in a (landscape) page at those coords.

In my printing event I do:

```
Dim mypoint As New PointF(1, 1192)
e.Graphics.DrawImage(My.Resources.littleSquare, mypoint)
```

This obviously doesn't work: I specify pixels but the driver expects inches(?) or what?

Tried to: `e.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Inch` with no luck.

I'd like a conversion method like:

```
Dim mypoint As New PointF(convertPixelsIntoInches(1), convertPixelsIntoInches(1192))
e.Graphics.DrawImage(My.Resources.littleSquare, mypoint)

Private Function convertPixelsIntoInches(ByVal pixels As Integer) As Single
    Return ??
End Function
```

Any hints? Thanks.

Comment: Create the image file on your local disk and view what is created.  This will lead you down the right path.  (1,1192) is not going to be a very wide image ( 1 pixel ).

Comment: no you didn't get the question. the image is fine, 50x50 pixels, the problem is with the coordinate conversion from pixels to whatever the printing system expects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it.

My pixel coordinates are **not fixed**, but relative to a 300dpi canvas, thus I have to do a double DPI conversion, like this:

```
e.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel
dpiX = e.Graphics.DpiX
dpiY = e.Graphics.DpiY

Dim mypoint As New PointF(convertPixelsIntoInchesX(1501), convertPixelsIntoInchesY(1192))
e.Graphics.DrawImage(My.Resources.myblacksquare, mypoint)

Private Function convertPixelsIntoInchesX(ByVal pixel As Integer) As Single
   Return CSng(pixel * dpiX / 300)
End Function

Private Function convertPixelsIntoInchesY(ByVal pixel As Integer) As Single
        Return CSng(pixel * dpiY / 300)
End Function
```